# How to send the Wifi configuration file over-the-air to iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, wifi, over-the-air

I know how to distribute the ad hoc app over-the-air to iPhone.
(The ipa and manifest plist are on my website)

I add the following link in the download page:

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&amp;url=http://www.xxx.com/app.plist">Install the Application</a>
```

When my user click on the link, iPhone will automatically download and install the App.

But now I want to send the wifi configuration file(created from iPhone Configuration Utility) to iPhone by OTA. (Cause my App is allowed to be used only in a certain wifi environment created by me.)

If there's a similiar way to let my user download(and then automatically install) the wifi configuration file from website by simply click a link?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should just host the file up on your server and have a second link on the download page.
The .moblieconfig will be downloaded and the phone should detect what it is then prompt the user to install it.